# Скачивание файла WebClient.DownloadFile

Tags: c#, download

Здравствуйте! Пишу программу скачивания файлов с интернета, столкнулся с интересной проблемой, которую не могу решить, она (проблема) заключается в следующем.

---

При скачивании файла, первый загружается без проблем, но повторное скачивание не работает, пытался использовать разные методы, ничего не помогает. Вот варианты, которые я использовал:

```
void download_Thread()
{
    try
    {
        startedThread2 = true;
        string outPath = Path.GetTempPath(),inPath = Environment.SystemDirectory;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
            {
                if (testSite(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) == true)
                {
                    Download tws = new Download(row, outPath, inPath);
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tws.new_download));
                    t.IsBackground = true;
                    t.Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
    startedThread2 = false;
}
```

Само скачивание, в нем при скачивании второго файла загрузка останавливается на 0 Кб

```
public void new_download()
{
    string Url = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string ResultFileName = outPath + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    try
    {
    string name;
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    Uri ur = new Uri(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(ur, outPath + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    myWebClient.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
```

Способ №2, в данном способе при загрузке 2-ого файла, программа останавливается на строке

```
using (HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())

public void new_download()
{
    string Url = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string ResultFileName = outPath + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    try
    {
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
    wr.Timeout = 5000;
    using (HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
    {
        Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];
        int bytesReadTotal = 0;
        FileStream fstr = new FileStream(ResultFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        while (true)
        {
            int n = str.Read(inBuf, 0, 100000);
            if ((n == 0) || (n == -1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, n);
            bytesReadTotal += n;
        }
        str.Close();
        fstr.Close();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
```

Что делать? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Попробуйте воспроизвести свою проблему на приложении без графического интерфейса. Если получится, кидайте нам код. Покамест не ясно, проблема у вас в коде скачивания, или в UI. Кстати: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. При повторном обращении на скачивание файла `myWebClient.DownloadFile` запрос подвисал, и вываливалось `WebException`. Приложение заработало после того, как все обращения `HttpsWebResponse`, которые шли до и после `WebClient`, были обёрнуты в `using`, аналогично `using (HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse());`.
По коду у вас вроде бы всё обернуто в `using` либо вызывается `Close()` `Dispose()`. Надо проверять ещё, нет ли незакрытого `HttpWebResponse` или `WebClient`, которые могут мешать.

Comment: Извините, что не отписался, да я уже нашел решение, спасибо!